# Why cant i play .avi movies in my JavaFX MediaPlayer

Tags: javafx, video-player

I'm working on a javaFX mediaplayer but when i run an .AVI file im getting a weird error.
My guess is that .avi isnt supported, if this is the case how can i make it support .avi?

How can i fix this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported protocol "c"
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:235)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:364)
at player.MoviePlayer.playMovie(MoviePlayer.java:38)
at player.MoviePlayer$1.handle(MoviePlayer.java:68)
at player.MoviePlayer$1.handle(MoviePlayer.java:57)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:456)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1199)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1148)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1146)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Do you know what codec is contained in the .avi file?

Comment: No i dont actually how do i get that?

Comment: You can use VLC to get the codec types used in the file.

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX 2.2 doesn't play avi movies.

You should convert your avi movie to a format with JavaFX understands.  Likely the best candidate format would be H.264 encoded video in a MP4 container.  You can use utilities like [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) to perform this kind of conversion.

The list of media containers, codecs and protocols supported by JavaFX is detailed in the [JavaFX 2.2 media javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).

Additionally, ensure that your target machine meets the [system requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2.htm) for the media type you wish to play.

You also need to supply the correct protocol to the media source when you try to play the media.  From your stack trace it looks like you are trying to play your media from the file system, therefore you need to include the `file:` protocol in the media source string as specified in the [Media constructor javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29).  For example:

```
Media media = new Media("file:/c:/media/warandpeace.mp4");
```